# Change office file associations to MS Office 2010

Tags: wine, libreoffice

I have freshly installed Ubuntu 12.10 64 bit on my HP Pavilion g6 laptop. Post installation I installed MS Office 2010 through wine. By default all office files viz. xls/x, doc/x, ppt/x are associated with libreoffice which I would like to change to MS Office. Here is an excerpt from the file /usr/share/applications/defaults.list

```
application/csv=libreoffice-calc.desktop
application/excel=libreoffice-calc.desktop
application/msexcel=libreoffice-calc.desktop
application/msword=libreoffice-writer.desktop
```

Please guide.

Answer (score 1):

To change file association, right click a file and choose **Properties**.

[image]

Once the new windows opens click on **Open with** to choose the application you want.  If the Application is not in the list click on **Show other applications**, to choose the right application, once done click on **Set as default**.  Once done click on **close**.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Mitch but my question is very specific to association with applications installed using wine.